# Do Java Calendars go from Mon-Sun or Sun-Sat?

Tags: java, calendar

Im trying to create code that will populate an array with the current months days, the final previous months days that would appear on a calendar and next months days that would appear on a calendar (showing a total of 42 total days) and was wondering if the Calendar class went from Monday to Sunday or Sunday to Saturday ?

Im using

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: Some docs say `of` gives "The int value follows the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)." [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html]. Why do you think it matters?

Comment: Okay thanks that's all i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it behave any way you want in terms of what day it "starts on".

Comment: Many calendar classes also support "locale" preferences which might vary from one machine to another, depending on where-in-the-world it is. It is a very good idea to treat all date/time values (in any language ...) as *opaque objects,* and to rely completely and entirely on that class's methods and properties to supply you with all the answers you need. For instance, don't necessarily assume that "the first day of the week" is *any* particular day. Let the class tell you. And, if you're testing against "magic numbers" like 1-7 ("or is it 0-6?", *etc.)*, define (if necessary) **constants.**

Answer (score 0):

After some reasearch as well as the comments and answers posted I realized my question has no value ... I was trying to do something completly different that was not needed.

My original question was does Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK index from Mon to Sun or Sun to Sat but it does not mater as I just used Constants.